# Отображается прямоугольник вместо рубля Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет.
Нужна помощь со знаком рубля в битрикс, на версиях win xp- win 7, браузер IE 11 знак рубля отображается как прямоугольник.

Нашел что многие также сталкивались с такой ситуацией. Нашел статью от Лебедева, где он отдает шрифты Ruble которые как раз подходят для старых версий браузеров и операционных систем.

Нужна помощь, может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает как ее решить. Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Причем тут битрикс или php? Знаки выводятся браузером. У каждого знака, буквы, цифры есть свой код, по которым в подключенном шрифте выводится нужный символ. Подключите на сайте шрифт, в котором имеется знак рубля и он будет выводится.

Comment: Дело в том, что если попробует через browserstack открыть страницы со знаком рубля, с любой операционной системы до windows 8  и любым браузером в той операционной системе, то - выдается прямоугольники с символами вместо рубля. Это старый вопрос, студия Лебедева уже озвучивала этот вопрос и у него есть решения. Лебедев выложил в свободный доступ шрифт RT_RUBL (вроде так называется) который позволяет решить эту проблему. Либо можно накатить модуль на битрикс https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/webdebug.ruble/ Который меняет шрифт рубля и тем самым отображения на всех версиях браузеров.

Comment: Что не отменяет моих слов, что можно подключить шрифт на сайте, хоть от Лебедева, хоть свой быстренько сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, для решения выбрал модуль:
marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/webdebug.ruble

Есть еще вариант с решением использовать шрифт от Артемия Лебедева.
Это проблема старая, более подробно ее описал в коммендарие выше.